# Facebook Graph API - Tagged Places in version 2.0

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I used the Graph API with javascript to fetch all of my data contained locations in v1.0.
( I used FB.api("/v1.0/me/locations", function (response) { ... }); )

I know that the updated version is 2.2 and the "locations" node is replaced by "tagged_places" node in v2.0 and above.

I also use the Graph API Explorer to test my results.
I try this, GET: /v2.2/me?fields=tagged_places
and the results are exactly what I want.

However, in my js code, I try: FB.api("/v2.2/me?fields=tagged_places", function (response) { ... });
and there is NO any results!

Besides,
I set version: 'v2.2' in Parse.FacebookUtils.init();
I also ask the permissions :user_tagged_places,user_photos,user_status,user_friends,user_about_me,user_birthday,read_stream in Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn();

I need almost all of the data of my checkins(a.k.a locations in v1.0/tagged_places in v2.0) to add into my database.
I try to fetch /me/photos, but the results are not satisfied. So I still need to use maybe this: FB.api("/v2.2/me?fields=tagged_places", function (response) { ... });

So... can anyone help me? please....

Comment: Yeah im having similar issues. Using the graph api explorer im getting data. In my app when i use `FB.api('me/tagged_places', function(response){});` its just returning an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

I went through permissions in groups testing them out and I figured out what the problem was. 
You need to have the permission of the item you were tagged in. 
So in my case I was tagged in photos, so I needed `user_photos` permission to gain access to `user_tagged_places`. It actually creates quite an issue because you need to know how a user was tagged to retrieve their tagged_places.

If a user was tagged at a place in a post you need a different permission than if they were tagged in a photo.